# SC-FDMA disadvantages

Tags: fft, ofdm, lte, sc-fdma

I understand the advantages of SC-FDMA over OFDM and I also understand the disadvantage of additional complexity (FFT block), are there another disadvantages?

Also, if $N$ has to be bigger than $M$ ($N>M$) then I don't understand why I don't lose rate as a result of padding with zeros instead of transmitting another data subcarriers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some more disadvantages:

- Channel estimation using pilots is harder, because you do not have orthogonal data on each frequency bin, compared to OFDM. That's why e.g. LTE uplink resorts to a midamble for channel estimation in uplink
- Application of non-linear MIMO detection algorithms is harder (i.e. more complex), because you essentially have coupled MxM elements from each transmit antenna, compared to 1x1 elements when using OFDM.
- In high SNR regions I think SC-FDMA does not perform as good as OFDM when considering a coded transmission with linear detectors.

Regarding the data loss: Even if $M<N$, there is no real loss, because the used bandwidth of your signal is only M frequency bins (ignoring any guard carriers). So, any other system can use the remaining N-M frequency bins.

Comment: Thanks! I'm wondering if converting the ofdm structure in DVB-T2 downlink into SC-FDM will make things better, what do you think? I guess you won't need the rotated constellation mechanism as you have inherent diversity over the frequency bins and hence you have greater immunity to fading and 0dB echo channels.

Comment: @Gabe Well, yes you have frequency diversity over the bins, but at the same time there is ISI in a multipath channel (without proper equalization). To really exploit this frequency diversity you would need 1) a very high frequency-selective channel 2) at least LMMSE detector and high SNR 3) high-complexity non-linear detector like sphere decoder. It's up to you to decide if this litte gain in diversity is worth the effort. You can look for "interleaved SC-FDMA" for more frequency-selectivity, or even vector-OFDM, which spreads all data over a very wide frequency range.

Comment: I'm discussing mainly that scenario of 0 dB echo channel (one and only one another path as powerful as the LOS path). Why does 2 true?and what do you need sphere decoder for? There is no MIMO involved in DVB-T2. Also,that's why VOFDM may be not relevant here. Is there another improvement to the DVB-T2 standard that you think might help in some scenarios?

Comment: 0dB echo path or any other multipath, you essentially have the following signal model for your single-carrier: y=Hd+n, where n is noise, H is the MxM (circulant) channel matrix and $d$ is the transmitted data. It's equivalent to a MxM MIMO system. You can now do linear equalization by "dividing by H". Here, only the LMMSE equalizer can gain diversity, but only for higher SNR. The ZF-equalizer will not gain diversity. Or you can use a non-linear technique, like a sphere-decoder to get to the d-values with even better performance. VOFDM gives you more frequency diversity by wider data spreading.

Comment: I tried reading Xia's paper about VOFDM but I haven't understood it entriely. How does it work exactly, how can it help me with frequency diversity and what is the cost?

Comment: Have a look here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.06833.pdf , equation (4). This is the transmit signal of V-OFDM. Might be easier to understand than Xia's formulation. Starting from this linear model and using a LMMSE-equalizer after CP removal, you can gain more frequency diversity (since each symbol is spread over multiple, farther apart, frequency bins). However, an entire decision on the best waveform for some system is far beyond the scope of this site, I believe.

Comment: @MaximilianMatthé Could you please talk a little more about "Channel estimation using pilots is harder", or give me some documents about the topic ? I don't understand why we don't use the same pilot pattern as in OFDM after the DFT and before IFFT and the channel estimation should be the same as in OFDM. I know in LTE PUSCH, we use a pilot symbol per slot, not the mixed pilot-data like in DL and I really confuse. Thanks

Comment: @AlexTP You can insert pilots as you describe, i.e. you leave some frequency bins empty for the pilots, and use the other frequency bins to transmit the single-carrier signal. This would essentially mix OFDM pilots with SC-FDMA data. I think a disadvantage is an increased PAPR due to the mix of both signals. I cannot tell you, why the LTE standard was really done as it is.